# Allowing access cancan / cancancan when id is not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

I'm trying to give access where an association exists using cancan.

It needs to work with both object attributes and accessible_by selection (so I can't use a block, unless someone tells me how I get around the error when I do that).

I've come up with a brutal hack.

```
lead.rb
has_many :recordings
has_many :emails

ability.rb

can :manage, Lead
can :manage, Recording, :lead_id => (1..Lead.pluck(:id).max).to_a
can :manage, Email, :lead_id => (1..Lead.pluck(:id).max).to_a
```

What I mean is lead_id is not null...

Is there any way I can do that without creating a 100,000 item array every time?

---

Extra info: It's worth noting that these are not the only controls in place on the Recording and Emails models, so it's important that I can add the extra permissions rather than reset and express them negatively.

Comment: what's the point of the sophisticated way to generate array? Why not just `lead_id: Lead.ids`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

### 1. A combined hash of abilities

**This is the [recommended approach](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities%3A-Best-Practice).** Use this, unless you have a good reason not to.

The idea here is to [combine](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities#combining-abilities) a `cannot` ability, in conjunction with `can`:

```
can :manage, Recording
cannot :manage, Recording, lead_id: nil
```

Note that the [order is important](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Ability-Precedence) here, so that the rule overriding is correct.

### 2. A block of abilities

By [defining the ability with a block](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks), you can form more complicated queries.

A simple implementation would be as follows:

```
can :manage, Recording do |recording|
  !recording.lead_id.nil?
end
```

However, in order to combine this ability with others, you must also [specify the SQL conditions](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks#fetching-records) when fetching records. This additional SQL controls `load_resource` actions, such as `index`:

```
can :manage, Recording, ["lead_id IS NOT NULL"] do |recording|
  !recording.lead_id.nil?
end
```

---

In order to keep this logic DRY, you could also consider defining your permissions in a block such as:

```
[Recording, Email].each do |model|
  can :manage, model
  cannot :manage, model, lead_id: nil
end
```

Comment: Yeah, that would be fine, except there are other more complex things going in alongside this. 
This approach only works if you are willing to wipe all of those other permissions.

to clarify, in other circumstances I'm specifying permissions based on an id which, if I try to reverse it to be expressed negatively, which I'd need to do to match the above, I'd end up with the exact same problem...

Comment: And I can't define it with a block, as mentioned, as this will only support object attributes, and not work with accessible_by e.g. on an index action, which is where I primarily need it.

Comment: *"This approach only works if you are willing to wipe all of those other permissions*" -- Yes, unfortunately this is one of the main problems/criticisms with `CanCan` - and is why many developers now prefer to use alternate approaches such as [`pundit`](https://github.com/elabs/pundit).

Comment: If your permission applies to only *some* `lead_id`s, then as far as I know the problem of "defining a list with 1000s of IDs" is unavoidable - unless there is some other attribute of the model that you can query, instead of the `id`. You can at least, however, cache the list of `id`s to improve performance.

Comment: Hi Tom, in this case, any id is fine. It's only nil values I want to restrict.

Comment: Is there a way of just putting a straight SQL statement in there?

Comment: SQL statements are [supported](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks#fetching-records), with some caveats. Might I suggest posing a new question on SO with your actual requirements?

Comment: Tom. Added the SQL version as an edit. Which works. It's a little unclear from the docs, which is a shame as this would likely solve most people's limitations. Happy to approve your answer, since it was really down to your sleuthing.

Comment: Thanks, I've tidied up my answer into a better structure, so that future readers will find all the information easily.

Answer (score 0):

I had this need, and here's a solution that is probably much faster. You don't have to hit the database with a `pluck`, and there's no reason to change a range to an array, as checking the range works fine (I'm not sure if this uses a range internally in the library, but ideally it would).

```
can :manage, [Recording, Email], :lead_id => (1..(2**31-1))
```

I'm using `cancancan`.